# What does this C++ template statement actually mean from syntactical and semantically context

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl

Please find below some usage of C++ template. I am not able to fully understand these from syntactical and semantically point of view, e.g., 
First this is declared, which I know :

```
template <class T>
class Queue {// some other statements};
```

Then this is declared, which I understood partially, need to know what does it mean from syntactical and semantically point of view :

```
template <class T>
class IntermittentQueue : Queue<T> {// some other statements};
```

And finally this statements, which I again didn't understand fully

```
template <class T>
typename IntermittentQueue<T>::Node* IntermittentQueue<T>::getNode(const node_ptr nodePtr) {// some other statements };
```

Comment: IntermittentQueue is a class template derived from the class template Queue. And getNode is a member of that class template which returns a pointer to the Node member of that class template.

Comment: templates provide instructions for creating classes that differ by the template arguments. For instance Queue<int>, Queue<char>. They can be inherited and instantiate other classes and components where "T" might be different.

Comment: @doug Thanks for your response. I am aware of this fact. I am more interested in knowing the other two usage. Out of the other two I can make out partially but not fully because if the internal is not known to me then I might have difficulty in instantiating these templates. So my main focus is on the other two.

Comment: @P.W Thanks for your clarification but I would like to know the usage of **typename** before _IntermittentQueue_.

Comment: @linard_in: Please see this post which has a detailed answer explaining this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: @P.W Thanks for this link and as well as for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T>
class IntermittentQueue : Queue<T> { /* some other statements */ };
```

This defines a new template class:

```
template <class T>
class IntermittentQueue { }
```

that at the same time inherits from another one, such as:

```
class Base { };
class Derived : Base { };
```

Solely, that in this case, the base class is an instantiation of another template class:

```
template <typename T>
class Base { };
class Derived : Base<int> { };
```

using the derived class' template parameter as template argument (and now we are back at the original code again...).

```
template <class T>
typename IntermittentQueue<T>::Node* IntermittentQueue<T>::getNode(const node_ptr nodePtr)
{ /* some other statements */ };
```

This is the implementation of one of the member functions of a template class. Step by step:

```
template <class T> // the class we are speaking off is a template class

typename IntermittentQueue<T>::Node* // return value of the function

IntermittentQueue<T>::getNode // function name with (template) class scope specified
                              // (just as with SomeClass::someMemberFunction)

 (const node_ptr nodePtr)         // function parameter(list)
 { /* some other statements */ }; // function body
```

Fine so far, but the return type might need further explanation:

```
typename IntermittentQueue<T>::Node*
```

The function returns a pointer to an object of inner class type `Node` of (template) class `IntermittentQueue`:

```
IntermittentQueue<T>::Node*
```

As inner type is a dependent type, you *need* to explicitly tell the compiler that this actually *is* a type at all, this is what the `typename` keyword then is used for; for details: there's already another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1312382) to the topic.

Just a side note here: Having typedefs for pointers (`node_ptr`) is *bad practice*, that's just information hiding and does not serve anything valuable for (the exception from: the pointer serves as a handle to some internal resource and is *not intended to be dereferenced* anywhere outside – then explicitly hiding the pointer nature is valid).

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation, it helped me in understanding **typename** before _IntermittentQueue_ usage. Thanks again.